# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) - Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: I get this error when I run the page]

I get this error message when I click the < li > or I refresh

```
                <ul class="sub-menuI">
        　　　　　　　　 <li>
                                <a href="javascript:loadContainer('../works/users.php','Filter student')">
                                                <span class="title1">担当者を追加/更新する </span>
                                </a>
                    　  </li>
                </ul>
```

this is my function inside loadFile.js

```
function loadContainer(durl){
 $('#loadingmessage').hide();
     $.ajax({
      url:durl,
      beforeSend:function(){
 $('#firstload').show();
      },
      success:function(data){
  $('#firstload').hide();
        $("#content-replacer").html(data);      
        
      }
      
    });    
}
```

Comment: It cant find the css file, check its location.

Comment: yes you are right, the link was broken, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

check if the php file work or change to use